# I'm trying to expand the scope of the default WP search algorithm. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: search

I'm aware that there is a plugin that will do this, but it is too broad for what I would like to add.

Below is my first attempt at expanding the search to query custom fields, but it's returning nothing. I've written code in the past to create queries, but this is my first time trying to modify a pre-existing one and I'm clearly missing something.

```
function st_search_all( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {

        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'page', 'attachment', 'post' ) );
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'inherit' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                array( 
                    'key'       => '_st_plaintext',
                    'value'     => "%{$query->get('s')}%",
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'Training Classes',
                    'value'     => "%{$query->get('s')}%",
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'External Content',
                    'value'     => "%{$query->get('s')}%",
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'st_search_all' );
```

The other thing is, I will need to include a search of the main content of pages/posts also, which this code doesn't attempt. What would that meta key be if I wanted to include it within the `meta_query`?

**EDIT:** Dumping the resulting query string after making @s_ha_dum's suggested changes (removing `%`s, adding the `OR` relationship, and removing the `post` type from the `post_type`) is returning the following (indention added). I'm not extremely familiar with SQL, but it appears that the query generated is requiring the title or content to match the query before it will even check any of the added fields. Am I misreading something? If not, how can I modify that through the WP API?

```
string(494) " 
  AND ((
        (dev_posts.post_title LIKE '%SBIR%') OR 
        (dev_posts.post_content LIKE '%SBIR%')
  )) AND 
    (dev_posts.post_password = '') AND 
    dev_posts.post_type IN 
    ('page', 'attachment') AND 
    (dev_posts.post_status = 'inherit') AND 
    ((dev_postmeta.meta_key = '_st_plaintext' AND 
      CAST(dev_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%SBIR%') OR 
      (mt1.meta_key = 'Training Classes' AND 
        CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%SBIR%') OR 
      (mt2.meta_key = 'External Content' AND 
        CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%SBIR%') )
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this temporarily to your `functions.php`. It will break things but you can see the `WHERE` clause. Be sure to remove it because things won't work right if you leave it there.

```
function dump_where($w){
 var_dump($w);
}
add_filter('posts_where','dump_where');
```

The first thing you should notice is that the `%` signs get escaped. Remove those and WordPress will add them back unescaped. If you only wanted one of those at the beginning or the end, but not both, this might be trickier. Luckily you don't.

Second, the default relationship appears to be `AND` so unless you want to enforce a match on every one of those `meta_key`s you should add a `relationship` to your meta query.

```
 $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array( 
                'key'       => '_st_plaintext',
                /* and the rest of your query */
```

Third, post content is already searched.You shouldn't have to do anything to make that happen.  Take a look at the `WHERE` clause my temporary code dumps and you should be able to see where that happens.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I've added the relation, removed the `post` value from the array and stripped the `%`s, but it still isn't returning what I would expect. I've edited the question to show the query being generated and what I think the issue is. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what you expect the query to return. If you can tell what is or isn't matching maybe I can tell you something.

Comment: I would expect the query to return matches to any one of the fields, but it's only returning posts that have a matching (title OR subject) AND (any one of the other fields queried). This does not appear to be what is happening.

Comment: That is the way `meta_query` gets built. [Looks like it is hard-coded](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/meta.php) but I may be wrong. That is a lot of code to digest. The only things I can think of is a regex replace of the `AND` (very tricky), or two queries.

Comment: Thanks. Knowing that helps a lot. Looks like this is less trivial that I'd hoped.